# How can an international student move his stuff to New York from TOronto

Tags: usa, international-travel, chinese-citizens

I am an international student from china, studying in University of Toronto, Toronto, Canada, I'm graduating this summer and get an offer from NYU for master, and I want to move or ship my stuff to there first, But I don't know how can I do that beside taking a flight, I thought about driving to there, but I haven't gotten my Study Visa for the US, I'm not sure what the border office would say about this, I'm afraid they might tell me to drive back. I have asked the UPS if they can ship my stuff and they say it can't be done without me having a permit to stay in US. I'm really running out of options..

Comment: Can you clarify why you want to move your things to New York before you have your US visa?

Comment: You mean clarify to the border office.

Comment: @user28850 No he means, why do you need to move your stuff before you start your master at NYU? If you will go there for studying, why don't you move at that time? (and store your stuff somewhere in Canada if you should move out of your current place early)

Comment: @Vince ok, the problem is that I am not going to stay in Canada nor coming back in short time, and if I carry all my belongs with me, that will be too much trouble, so I want to move half of my stuff to there first

Answer (score 3):

How much stuff do you have?

You will not be able to move personal effects (term customs uses for your stuff) between countries without a residence visa. If you show up at the Peace Bridge border crossing with a rented truck they will deny you entry as it looks like you are moving down there (which you are). Note that the rented truck is no problem at all, but you will have to drive it back to Canada.

If you have a lot to move you can use a freight company (UPS is a parcel delivery service). The container will simply be stored at a bonded warehouse until you arrive and clear it through customs. Not worth it unless you can justify a half-container.

The most cost-effective way will be waiting until your US visa comes through. If you need to move out now, find a self-storage in St. Catherines (there's lots). Rent a truck and drive down there. Put everything in self-storage and return the truck to Toronto.

After you get a place in NY, rent a truck and drive up to the self-storage. Deal with US customs, drive to NYC, unpack and return the truck.

Canada won't care (or even check) on the way out, and an empty truck coming in is no problem, especially with a new US visa and a self-storage receipt. You will need to tell the rental company you are picking up stuff in Canada as there is extra paperwork they need to produce, but this happens all the time and is no problem at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answering, I really appreciated. But I am now thinking about flight there carrying two luggages with me and my friend will pick me up in the airport. The reason I want to do that is i compared the cost of using shipping company and drive the truck my self to there, flight doesn't cost too much comparing these methods. Plus there is this VISA problem,  I'm going back home in June, and can't wait for the VISA, so it would be easy for me just me make a fight trip to there and settle things. Thank you again for your kind help.